# Posts with multiple authors with different roles

Tags: posts, user-roles, list-authors

I want to assign multiple authors per post. I'm aware of the excellent [Co-Authors Plus](https://wordpress.org/plugins/co-authors-plus/).

I want to assign different roles, per author, per post. That is, author one could be 'writer', author two could be 'photographer', author three could be 'designer'. These roles don't need to influence how these users interact with the post itself (meaning they are not site-wide user roles).

What is the best way to go about this?

I'm aware of [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/128377/multiple-authors-with-different-author-roles), but it doesn't actually provide a solution and presumes changing Co-Authors Plus, which is not ideal.

Comment: If you will not receive the answer, try to ask here: https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/co-authors-plus

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you just need simple relationship handling as metadata, maybe only with little custom UI handling.

It could be easy handled for example by [Posts 2 Posts](https://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-to-posts/%20%22Posts%202%20Posts) plugin, like in [related documentation page](https://github.com/scribu/wp-posts-to-posts/wiki/Posts-2-Users).

Comment: That plugin looks excellent. I was not aware of it.